# How to I remove "Key" and "Value" text from JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form and I am converting that form inputs to a object using the below code:

```
var inputs = $("form :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
    return {
        Key: x.name,
        Value: $(x).val()
    };
});
```

This returns me something like this:

```
[
  {"Key":"spouseFirstName","Value":"Jack"},
  {"Key":"spouseLastName","Value":"Jill"},
  {"Key":"numberOfChildren","Value":"2"},
  {"Key":"child1Age","Value":"5"},
  {"Key":"child2Age","Value":"3"},
  {"Key":"","Value":"SUBMIT"}
]
```

But what I wanted is:

```
[
  {"spouseFirstName":"Jack"},
  {"spouseLastName":"Jill"},
  {"numberOfChildren":2},
  ...
]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES5 (javascript that runs eveywhere)

```
var inputs = $("form :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
    var ret = {};
    ret[x.name] = $(x).val();
    return ret;
});
```

ES2015 - in all good browsers now (not IE) uses [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
var inputs = $("form :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
    return {
        [x.name]: $(x).val()
    };
});
```

if you are going to use ES2015, use it all - all good browsers can also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - note, using [return object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax)

```
var inputs = $("form :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, (x, y) => ({
        [x.name]: $(x).val()
    })
);
```

or

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, (x, y) => ({[x.name]: $(x).val()}));
```

but that's maybe not so readable

and since you don't use Y at all, you can use the single argument version of the arrow function

```
var inputs = $("form :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, x => ({
        [x.name]: $(x).val()
    })
);
```

or

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, x => ({[x.name]: $(x).val()}));
```

Comment: I just thought of this and you answered. Awesome.

Comment: ES5 - javascript that most browsers currently support ... ES2015, aka ES6, is the emerging new javascript (most good browsers will run the "real ES2015" code sample, i.e with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) )

Comment: added explanation and links to answer

Comment: one more thing.. i get now {"numberOfChildren":"2"},{"child1Age":"5"},{"child2Age":"3"},{"":"SUBMIT"}] Can i filter to get only input Type = Text and Select

Comment: that's because it's picking up the submit button ... perhaps `$("form :input:not([type=submit])"))`